# How to use unsafe code convert a int to the byte[] buffer?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm writing a high-performance component that converts a series of int to bytes, but I only know C#.

I've tried to understand the source code for BitConverter, but I still don't know how to complete the following methods.

```
public static unsafe void Int32ToBytes(int value,byte[] buffer,int offset) {

}

public static unsafe void BytesToInt32(byte[] buffer,int offset,out int value) {

}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you understand what endianness is and how 4 bytes can be shifted into how an int32 is represented on your processor?

Comment: `fixed (byte* p = &buffer[offset]) *(int*)p = value;`

Comment: `fixed (byte* p = &buffer[offset]) value = *(int*)p;`

Comment: If the input data is from a file or stream, use File.ReadAllBytes() to get the data into bytes in the first place.  Converting an int at a time is much slower.